# Receiving Email with Java using imap throws connection timed out

Tags: java, imap

I'm trying to create a program with Java that come into my `gmail` account and prints the sender, subject, and body of unread emails.

**Here's the code:**

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;

public class CheckingMails {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
        try {
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
            Store store = session.getStore();
            store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "email@gmail.com", "password");
            Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            Message msg = inbox.getMessage(inbox.getMessageCount());
            Address[] in = msg.getFrom();
            for (Address address : in) {
                System.out.println("FROM:" + address.toString());
            }
            Multipart mp = (Multipart) msg.getContent();
            BodyPart bp = mp.getBodyPart(0);
            System.out.println("SENT DATE:" + msg.getSentDate());
            System.out.println("SUBJECT:" + msg.getSubject());
            System.out.println("CONTENT:" + bp.getContent());
        } catch (Exception mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the errors that appear, I do not understand the reason for these errors.

Anyone knows how I can fix it?

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Connessione scaduta;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connessione scaduta
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:670)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at CheckingMails.main(CheckingMails.java:12)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connessione scaduta
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:321)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:237)
    at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:116)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.<init>(IMAPProtocol.java:115)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.newIMAPProtocol(IMAPStore.java:685)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:636)
    ... 8 more
```

Thank You.

Comment: For increasing the chance to get an answer, you should add the full stacktrace. "... 8 more" is an indecation for an incomplete one.

Comment: I'm not really firm regarding italian language but I think "Connessione scaduta" means "The connection timed out" which leads to think about proxy or firewall issues.

Comment: Yes, "Connessione scaduta" = "Connection timed out"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code. The translated error from italian to english is : `connection timed out`

Try adding the following properties to your prop object to override the default ones:

```
props.setProperty("mail.imap.port", "993");
props.setProperty("mail.imap.connectiontimeout", "5000");
props.setProperty("mail.imap.timeout", "5000");
```

If the error persists, you can use the command `telnet imap.gmail.com {port number}` in cmd line to check the port connection. The error might be caused by a firewall or networking problems.